# Syncing a Google Calendar that's created from a URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've manually added my gym's calendar to my google calendar using the URL https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/addbyurl and pasted in the gym's webcal url. This works and the new calendar appears as an "Other Calendar" within google calendar. However when I book more gym classes they are not being synced by google.

If I manually unsubscribe the "other calendar" and recreate it again the new fitness classes appear on my desktop and my android phone. This recreation forces a syncronisation.

So I tried writing some Google app script to remove the "other calendar" and recreate it. Then run the app script via a time based trigger.

The script runs OK and the removal works but I cannot find a way to recreate the calendar via a script. So I'd really apprieciate some help to finish off this coding or force Google calendar to resync its "other calendar" (which it should anyway).

Here is my coding:

```
    myCalendar('My Bookings');

    function myCalendar(mycal) {

      var calendars;
      var pageToken;
      do {
        calendars = Calendar.CalendarList.list({
          maxResults: 100,
          pageToken: pageToken
        });
        if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
            var calendar = calendars.items[i];
            Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.summary, calendar.id, calendar.description);
            if (calendar.summary == mycal) {
              // get works it's my gym calendar, but why doesn't it show the webcal url?
              var mycalendar = Calendar.CalendarList.get(calendar.id);
              Logger.log(mycalendar);
              // remove works
              Calendar.CalendarList.remove(calendar.id);
              Logger.log('removed');
              // The calendar has been removed
              // But how do I recreate the same calendar from a url?
            }
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('No calendar found.');
        }
        pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
      } while (pageToken);
    }
```

Comment: I think there must be a way other than deleting the calendar and adding it again. Is that calendar public, if so could you share its link please?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Muhammet. The gym calendar is personal however a test calendar is available from here: https://visihow.com/Use_webcal_url_to_add_a_calendar_to_google_calendar it's webcal://suncountypanthers.com/webcal.ashx?IDs=1030  If you create the google calendar from the webcal url it creates a calendar called "Sun County Panthers" and it contains 16 future events.

Comment: The visihow website says that google syncs every 24 hours. Which is not good when you book gym classes for the same day. They won't appear in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you say.

```js
function myFunction () {
  var id = 'nmkf37p4k6onnhsa8a770u0m8adqd3v2@import.calendar.google.com' 
  //change this id. 
  //You can find your calendar's id in Calendar Settings > Integrate Calendar
  
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id)
  
  calendar.unsubscribeFromCalendar() // this line makes you unsubscribe
  CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(id) // this makes you resubscribe
}
```

But please let me know, how do you add new events to the calendar? For example you add them via `calendar.google.com` on your browser, but you don't see them on your Android phone. Is this what is happening?

Comment: Thanks Muhammet, that works, so it's time to give it a test... The calendar was initially created by going to the gym's website and copying their webcal address which is unique to my membership. My Android phone and my Amazon echo both sync with google quite often. But google doesn't appear to sync to this "read only" calendar at all. Anyway it's time to test the complete solution. I'll keep you updated and thanks again.